# use window.addEventListener('/load', myFunction); on the second html page?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

Can you show me how I can modify this javascript code? I want to execute it when my second page is loaded (capture.html), but not on the first one (index.html):

```
window.addEventListener('/load', myFunction);
```

It work fine in the index.html page, but I need it also in the capture.html page. I tried:

```
window.addEventListener('/capture/load', myFunction);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Your html file is not attached to the last line? It would be better to include any code relevant to the question directly in the question though, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the route for which you want the event to be attached (at least not inside the `addEventListener()` API like you are trying to do). There is no '/load' or '/capture/load' event. But you can define logic in your handler that depends on the current route like follows:

```js
const handler = () => {
    const {pathname} = window.location;

    if (/\/?capture(\.html?)?$/.test(pathname)) {
        // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', handler);
```

You can also perform the same check before even attaching the event listener if you want.

Answer (score 0):

`/capture/load` isn't an event. `load` is, so perhaps add an `id` to the body of your document, and then test for that.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.id === 'capture') {
    console.log(true);
  } else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<body id="capture">
  <div />
</body>
```

Comment: thank you,  so i can add my code like that ?

      if(document.body.id === 'capture') {
      console.log(true);
     //my code;

   }